# Does Statistics::Descriptive percentile method work as documented?

Tags: perl, statistics

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Statistics::Descriptive;
use 5.012;

my @data = ( -2, 7, 7, 4, 18, -5 );
my $stat = Statistics::Descriptive::Full->new();
$stat->add_data(@data);
say ($stat->percentile(100) // "undef"); # return 18. OK.
say ($stat->percentile(0) // "undef"); # return undef instead of "-inf". see doc below
```

[Statistics::Descriptive doc](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Statistics-Descriptive/lib/Statistics/Descriptive.pm#Full_Methods).

Comment: Please report this as a bug on CPAN.  You will increase the chances of it being fixed soon if you also include a test, perhaps as a patch to the existing `t/descr.t` test.

Comment: @toolic https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=62055

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same outcome on ActiveState 5.12.2 64-bit on a Windows platform. You answered your own question: it does not work as documented.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use Statistics::Descriptive;
use Math::Bigint;

use 5.012;

my @data = ( -2, 7, 7, 4, 18, -5 );
my $stat = Statistics::Descriptive::Full->new();
$stat->add_data(@data);
say(Math::BigInt->is_inf($stat->percentile(0)));
```

returns `0`

Edit : as rafl points out, on a Windows system `perl -e "print(9**9**9);"` will give `1.#INF` instead of `inf`. As `inf` apparently isn't implemented yet in my version, the Statistics package won't be able to return `inf` and returns undefined instead.

Edit2 : As it turns out OP works on Linux and can return `inf`, the error is probably inherent to the `Statistics::Descriptive` package.

Comment: Note that the C library on win32 formats a double containing Infinity or Not A Number as `1.#INF`, `-1.#INF`, `1.#QNAN`, and `-1.#IND`, instead of `inf`, `-inf`, `nan`, and `-nan`, as you might expect from most Unix platforms. `Math::BigInt`s `is_inf` and `is_nan` methods don't cope with that yet (although work is underway to fix this both in the perl core and `Math::BigInt`).

Comment: @rafl : thanks for the clarification. I noticed already, and I'm quite sure that OP runs a Windows as well. That is more than likely why the percentile function gives this result. But unless OP states what his setup is, this cannot be said for sure.

Comment: I'm actually running linux (Ubuntu and CentOS)

Comment: @David B: You have it with earlier versions of Perl as well?

Comment: @Joris Meys I don't know. I'm not using earlier versions now and did not use this method before.

Comment: @David B: Just do the test: if `perl -e "print(9**9**9);"` doesn't return **inf**, then that is the cause of the problem. Otherwise, it's something else in the implementation of the Statistics module.

Comment: @Joris Meys: It does return `inf`.

Comment: @David: That rules out platform-dependent issues. So I guess it's really in the implementation itself. Thx for the report.